# WiX installer trigger rollback when the user cancels installation

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, rollback, installation-package

If installation fails during the process, it rolls back recent changes by the installer, but when the user cancels it through the *Cancel* button the installer just fails and does not rollback recent changes.

How can we trigger a rollback process if the user cancels installation through a button?

Comment: You'll need to say which Cancel button. Is it one in the UI sequence? Is it the one that is sometimes shown during the actual install and progress bar?

Comment: It is defined through Bootstrapper.

Comment: Added an answer even though this is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

***Rollback***: This is old, but just for the record: if the installer has not hit the **`installation sequence`** (where files and registry entries and such things are being added or modified) - as opposed to the **`user interface sequence`** (where installation choices and settings are gathered) - there should be nothing to roll back. Rollback happens when the installation has made changes on the system and a fatal error occurs so the whole installation has to be undone. This is after the user interface sequence when you normally see a progress bar on the screen.

***Installation Transaction***: It is possible to erroneously make changes from the UI-sequence. *`It is always a design error to do so`* since no rollback will happen except for actions between **`InstallInitialize`** and **`InstallFinalize`** in the **`InstallExecuteSequence`**. Any other changes done from elsewhere in other sequences will not be rolled back. The sequence from InstallInitialize until and including **`InstallFinalize`** is the part of an installation that runs as a transaction that can be rolled back, and all other sequences should not change the system (but sometimes they do).